# Suggest a way to lift these functions

Tags: scala

Can you suggest a way to lift these two functions? Thanks!

```
def maxY(f: (Int, Int) => Int, z: Int) = (0 to z).filter(f(0, _) <= z).max
def maxX(f: (Int, Int) => Int, z: Int) = (0 to z).filter(f(_, 0) <= z).max
```

Comment: "lift"?  What does that mean?  What languages?  Your question is hard for me to understand.

Comment: @duffymo the language is in tag (scala), the [lifting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395697/haskell-newbie-question-what-is-lifting) is a term of computer science

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the education on both.  I didn't know.

Comment: Can you specify a bit more about your use case?  And do you mean manually or create something that will automatically do it given an arbitrary `((Int, Int) => Int => Int) => Int`?

Comment: my question's basically asking how to lift a tuple. Instead of duplicating a large part of the code above, I could use a lifted function like maxLifted(i: Int)(f: (Int, Int) => Int, z: Int): Int. Now I think this isn't practical since tuple's an odd structure.

Comment: Don't understand the question. Can you specify the type signature of the result you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert function to partial applied function and then use tuple instead of list of parameters:

```
def maxWithTuple(buildTuple: Int => (Int, Int), f: (Int, Int) => Int, z: Int) = 
  (0 to z).filter(i => (f _).tupled(buildTuple(i)) <= z).max
```

Sure this is not solution your are looking for, but demonstrates how to separate building of arguments and call of function.

`buildTuple` is method that constructs tuple that used as parameters list